# horizontal multiselect checkboxes in django admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Hopefully this is a simple fix, although I haven't found anything through searching.
I am using this code in admin.py to make my manytomany field appear as checkboxes in admin.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},
    }
```

But, I have about 10 choices, which is annoying as a vertical list. Is there a way to get  the checkboxes to display horizontally or even more flexibly as 2 columns of five choices (or some other arbitrary look)?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered through another search that this can be done by modifying the widget multiple_input.html file. not the best solution, but it worked